# PHP imap_open ошибка Connection refused

Tags: php, imap

Пытаюсь подключиться к почтовому серверу для получения писем

```
$mbox = imap_open("{mail.nvbs.ru:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "хххх@nvbs.ru", "ххххх");
print_r(imap_errors());
```

В ответ получаю

> Can't connect to mail.nvbs.ru,993: Connection refused

В php `OpenSSL` включен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в 1С получение почты работает с такими настройками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант, предлагаемый гуглом пробовал, не помогает

```
<?php
   $mbox = imap_open("{w2010ExchangeServer:993/imap/ssl}", $user, 
       $password, NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI'));
?>
```

Comment: Это не связано с блокировкой некоторых сайтов?

Comment: А к какому серверу вы пытаетесь подключиться? Exchange или ещё какой?

Comment: Можете связаться с вашим сервер провайдером и спросить у них открыт доступ к порту `993`. И еще один момент откуда вы пытаетесь соединиться к мейл серверу? то есть у вас есть на своем хостинге протокол `SSL`?

Comment: @Alexander. Exchange

Comment: Connection refused значит либо у пользователя нет прав на общение с сервером, либо у вашего сервера где запускается скрипт нет разрешения (прав) на общение с сервером почты, ну и наконец это может быть брандмауэр или неправильные настройки конфигурации.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте подключиться не используя протокол с помощью [netcat](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=netcat):

```
nc -v mail.nvbs.ru 993
```

Может быть дело не в IMAP, а в том, что вы в принципе не можете подключиться к серверу, например, из-за настроек сетевого фильтра на вашей стороне. Ошибка "Connection refused" говорит о том что, скорее всего, именно в этом причина.

При успешном подключении вы получите примерно такой вывод

```
$ nc -v mail.nvbs.ru 993
Connection to mail.nvbs.ru 993 port [tcp/imaps] succeeded!
^C
```

Если соединения даже так не происходит, но никакие попытки выбрать настройки IMAP не помогут исправить ситуацию.

Comment: nc: connect to mail.nvbs.ru port 993 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

почтовик не хочет пускать, надо проверять права скорее всего.

Answer (score -1):

На сайте php.net [пишут](http://php.net/imap-open):

> Since Version 5.3.2 there's a 6th parameter available to disable
>   authentication with GSSAPI or NTLM:
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $mbox = imap_open("{w2010ExchangeServer:993/imap/ssl}", $user, $password, NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI'));
> ?>
> ```

Может быть это ваш вариант?

Comment: Это первое, что я нашел :)
Но к сожалению не помогло. Будем логи почтовика смотреть, как у инженера время появится.

Comment: @thecoder об этом надо было написать в вопросе.